# SharePoint 2013 - Error while creating the web parts in vs 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I have SharePoint server 2013 install on server and vs 2010 present in other PC. I have developed a test visual web parts using vs 2010 on my local PC. The visual web part is successfully build. But when I try to deploy the web parts, I am getting the below error.

```
Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Also I am not able to generated the `.wsp` file in bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's impossible to deploy a farm solution to a remote server use visual stuido.you need

- Building a local test environment
- Or create wps file manually use [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks for you answer. It is very help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create manually wsp file by right clicking project folder and click on package in visual studio.

so it will generate wsp file in bin folder.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When I click on package in vs then I am getting the error as "Package failed". Can you help me.